# Ploting Countries in R Maps Library : Gray boundaries with FILL=TRUE

Tags: r, maps

I am trying to plot countries in R Maps. However, when I use FILL=TRUE all my countries boundaries are drawn in black. I want them in Gray. This is my code:

```
library(maps)       # Provides functions that let us plot the maps
library(mapdata)    # Contains the hi-resolution points that mark out the Cnt 


countries=c("Argentina","Armenia","Australia","Bahrain","Belgium","Botswana","Bulgaria","Canada",   "Chile","Tawain",   "Croatia","Cyprus", "Czech Republic",   "Denmark","Egypt","UK:Great Britain","Finland", "France",   "Georgia",  "Germany",  "China:Hong Kong",  "Hungary",  "Indonesia",    "Iran", "Ireland",  "Israel",   "Italy",    "Japan",    "Jordan",   "Kazakhstan",   "Korea",    "Kuwait",   "Lebanon",  "Lithuania",    "Malaysia", "Malta",    "Morocco",  "Netherlands",  "New Zealand",  "UK:Northern Ireland",  "Norway",   "Oman", "Palestine",    "Poland",   "Portugal", "Qatar",    "Russia",   "Saudi Arabia", "Serbia",   "Singapore",    "Slovak Republic",  "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Spain",    "Sweden",   "Thailand", "Turkey",   "United Arab Emirates", "USA")                  

map('world', resolution=1, col="darkgray")
map('world', countries, resolution=1, fill = T, col = "royalblue", add = T)
map('world', resolution=1,col="darkgray", add=TRUE)
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks
Jº

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of the boundaries, add the argument border='darkgrey'. This argument is not listed explicitely in the man page for 'map' because it is in fact an argument for the call to 'polygon'. It is mentioned in the '...' segment of the man page, though.

`map('world', countries, resolution=1, fill = T, 
      col = "royalblue", border="darkgrey", add = T)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex! After reading the help it says that "resolution=1" is not working with fill=TRUE... :-(

Comment: Is there a reason you need "resolution=1"? The thinning algorithm in maps is not symmetric, and this means the same border may be thinned differently in two directions. As a result, the polygons will no longer fit exactly an in some cases you could even see tiny blank lines between some polygons. That's why I recently changed the behaviour for fill==TRUE. Full resolution ("resolution=0") looks much better.

Comment: not really, I was just trying to see what would give better resolution. Thanks Alex.